# Javascript Storing Regexp screws the original format

Tags: regex, stringify

I have an angular app where a user can add a regexp in a form, a value like:

```
github\.com/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)
```

When I store this in the localStorage and I inspect the localStorage:

```
github\\\\.com\\/([A-Za-z0-9\\\\-\\\\_]+)\\/([A-Za-z0-9\\\\-\\\\_]+)
```

When I retrieve in Javascript elsewhere this value I get:

```
github\\.com\/([A-Za-z0-9\\-\\_]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9\\-\\_]+)
```

This is not the original regexp and the `match` method in Javascript can't work.

NOTE: after submitting the form, I store the object with:

```
localStorage.myobject = JSON.stringify(myobject);
```

Comment: Pass the string to the RegExp constructor after you retrieve from localstorage: `new RegExp('github\\.com\/([A-Za-z0-9\\-\\_]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9\\-\\_]+))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of overescaping here, just use

```
github[.]com/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)
```

and initialize it via a `RegExp` constructor so as not to have to escape the regex delimiter `/`. A dot inside `[]` loses its special meaning and only matches a literal dot, the hyphen at the end of the character class only matches a literal hyphen, and the `_` does not have to be escaped at all anywhere in the pattern:

```js
var tst = "github.com/Test1-Text/Test2";
var pattern = "github[.]com/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)";
console.log(new RegExp(pattern).test(tst));
```

**UPDATE**:

When using patterns from external sources, you need to use the constructor notation. Make sure your regex patterns are stored as literal strings (if you had `RegExp("C:\\\\Folder")`, make sure it is stored as `C:\\Folder`), and when reading the value in it will be automatically be usable with the `RegExp` constructor.

Comment: This **is** a trick to solve this particular problem, but is there a way to deal with general strings with ``\``s? :/